# Python Console commands

Tags: python, cmd, console

```
def do_create(self, arg):
        """Create a new instance of BaseModel, save it to JSON, and print its id"""
        arg_list = arg.split()
        if len(arg_list) == 0:
            print("** class name missing **")
        else:
            class_name = arg_list[1]
            if class_name not in self.classes:
                print("** class doesn't exist **")
            else:
                new_instance = globals()[class_name]()
                new_instance.save()
                print(new_instance.id)
```

Please I need explanation to the code above

After running the executable, then running command on the console I get error messages that my list is out of range the comman I mean is as follows create BaseModel.

Note:
This is the part where we have some issues
else:
class_name = arg_list[1]

Comment: The first item in a list is at index `0`. Are you sure you don't mean `arg_list[0]`?

Comment: How are you calling the function? What is the value of `arg`?

Comment: Your code expects it to be a string with at least 2 words, the second word is the class name. The error happens if there's only one word.